# Is netfilter isolation by namespace

Tags: kubernetes, netfilter

I used to think netfilter at the node level, so iptables rule only for node, so istio maybe inject iptable rule with the pod ip on initContainer

but i research chaos-mesh recently, it broken this point, i try to use [nsexec](https://github.com/chaos-mesh/nsexec)

i create a demo pod on node A and execute `nsexec -n /proc/xxxxxx/ns/net -l iptables -L`, iptable rules is different from node rules

when i try to add a output rule, it is work well, only for this pod

is netfilter isolation by namespace?

Comment: Are you using any [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)?

Comment: use from iaas provider , but there is no relationship between cni and this case , maybe?

Comment: Well, it's important information to replicate your issue. Which IaaS provider are you using? How did you setup your cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is netfilter isolation by namespace?`

Can [be done](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html).

`...a demo pod on node A and execute nsexec -n /proc/xxxxxx/ns/net -l iptables -L, iptable rules is different from node rules`

What happens here is `nsexec` loads `iptables` from its own mount namespace and execute it in the pod isolated namespace. As you wished, the pod gets a different iptables rules.

Comment: i has other question: i used to execute nsenter -n --target POD.Container.PID enter pod's network namespace on node, and execute iptables -L, but the output is node's iptables rules, and i add a rule , also work on node level,   why ?

Comment: `nsenter` is a different program, post this question as new one.